# NLTK: How to create a corpus from csv file

Tags: python, csv, nlp, nltk, tf-idf

I have a csv file as

```
col1         col2      col3

some text    someID    some value
some text    someID    some value
```

in each row, col1 corresponds to the text of an entire document. I would like to create a corpus from this csv. my aim is to use sklearn's TfidfVectorizer to compute document similarity and keyword extraction. So consider

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize, stop_words='english')
tfs = tfidf.fit_transform(<my corpus here>)
```

so then i can use

```
str = 'here is some text from a new document'
response = tfidf.transform([str])
feature_names = tfidf.get_feature_names()
for col in response.nonzero()[1]:
    print feature_names[col], ' - ', response[0, col]
```

how do i create a corpus using nltk?
what form/data structure should the corpus be so that it can be supplied to the transform function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `read_csv` from the `pandas` library. Here is the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

You can install pandas by running `pip install pandas` at the command line. Then loading the csv and selecting that column should be as easy as the below:

```
data = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)
docs = data['col1']

tfs = tfidf.fit_transform(docs)
```

Comment: thanks man, however this method is not accurate. docs is still a series object and not a list of strings. hence my fit_transform does not work. any idea on how to convert a dataframe column to a list of values?

Comment: found it. it should be docs=data['col1'].tolist() :) if you update your answer, i will accept

Comment: Ah good call, looks like passing a 2d array (the dataframe) to `fit_transform` doesn't work. However, the 1d array should work, so just grabbing the Series with `data['col1']` is enough (no need to convert `Series` to `list`). Updated.

Comment: i'm afraid i have to convert it to list. otherwise it still receives a pandas.Series :) thanks for your help.

Comment: What versions of pandas and sklearn are you using? The Series works for me on sklearn `0.17` and pandas `0.17.0`.

Comment: i am also using 0.17. i'll give it another try